# Saving a result from stored procedure in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, save

I want to retrieve a project id from my project table in SQL Server.

I created a stored procedure like this:

```
create proc spFindProjectID
   (@customerid int)
as
begin 
    select Project.pID
    from Project
    where Project.cID=@customerid
end
```

Now in my C# I execute that proc like this:

```
 public int findid(int id)
 {
        con = connect("igroup9_test1ConnectionString");
        using (SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("[spFindProjectID]", con))
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            try
            {
                sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerid", id);

                sqlComm.CommandTimeout = 600;
                sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }
            return
        }
    }
```

I want to save the result from the procedure and return it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Let's have a look at the *documentation* for [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx):

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. ... *For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.*

You're calling a stored procedure, which is none of the 3 listed statements.

I assume your

```
select Project.pID
from Project
where Project.cID=@customerid
```

query returns only one cell, you can use [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which returns the first column of the first row as `object`.

For example;

```
sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerid", id);
int value = (int)sqlComm.ExecuteScalar();
return value;
```